Switchover Contactor Logic
The contactor logic in the image is for a switchover power supply (from Grid power to PV inverter EPS/UPS output):

The idea is that when there is a grid fault, then T1 changes state. This causes K1 (NC contactor) to OPEN (KC1 energized), and K2 (NO contactor) to close (KC2 energized) only after K1 is OPEN via KA1.
Once the grid fault has cleared, then T1 should return to it's original state; de-energizing KC2 and KC1.
How can I ensure that K1 and K2 contactors aren't closed at the same time once KC1 and KC2 are de-energized?

EDIT: ADDED NEW CONTACTOR LOGIC WITH EXTRA AUX. CONTACT


Your schematic seems incomplete. Where are the symbols and wiring for K1 and K2?

This is only showing the logic, not the Power circuit with K1 and K2.
K1 is NC (when KC1 is de-energized), K2 is NO (when KC2 is de-energized).

added the rest of the schematic

Does anyone have an idea on this one?

Your control strategy is wrong. It risks connection of both power sources simultaneously and back-feeds from grid to UPS (probably destroying it) or back-feed onto the grid from your UPS (overloading it as you try to supply power to the neighbourhood - as well as electrocuting the lineman trying to repair the network).
You need an automatic transfer switch with mechanical interlocks and enough time delay to prevent instantaneous connection during transfer.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. At the very least both circuits should use NO contacts for the power and the coils should be cross-interlocked so that one has to be de-energised before the other can be energised. You may need to add an auxiliary NC contact block to achieve this.

Thanks for the feedback.
I think that by adding a NO aux. contact to the K1 coil could work as an electrical interlock, whilst maintaining the power contactors as per my original version (1 NC, 1NO)?
In this way the 2 contactors would never be CLOSED at the same time either in normal operation, in an undervoltage/grid failure, and when switching back to normal operation...
I added the figure showing what I mean

I don't like it. I don't know what the idea is with the unnamed time switch on the left and I don't think you have considered all the failure modes and what happens during switching of one to the other. I suspect there will be an instant when both are connected. You need to clean up the schematic and I recommend that you don't switch neutrals (as you are doing with K1 and K2) as this makes debugging and fault-finding so much more difficult and error prone.
